# Running azure pipelines after 15days of the trigger

Tags: triggers, cron, azure-pipelines

My requirement is, i have to run azure pipeline after 15days of the trigger. I have 2 pipelines where first pipeline will execute and after that pipeline is started, the second pipeline should trigger after 15days only. How can i do that? Can we tweak cron to do this?

I tried using cron but there is no way to set this up.

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a remind of [accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box type of trigger to achieve it according to Microsoft document at present.

But you can make the job depends on an agentless job that includes `delay task` to pause execution of the pipeline for a fixed delay time. Please refer to doc:[Delay task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delay?view=azure-devops)

for example:

1 add a delay task in an agentless job and configure delay time 21600 minutes(15 days)
[image]

2 make the job depend on agentless job
[image: dependencies]

3 set build trigger
[image: build trigger]

Note :set build job timeout to 0

Comment: If it helps you, you could accept it as answer .if not, i'll stay focus on your issue.